# Google maps API Authorization failure

Tags: android, google-maps

I am unable to connect to Google MAP API and continuously getting this error:

```
Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name:, API Key: AIzasDDWrwnmz8QWHp-O9ywE7uavUOF7Yrk0SJM, Certificate Fingerprint: 09CF42213E0E2C4C7C8D790B……..
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I have made sure the following:

- Key in my Android manifest correctly matches with the Key in Google
  API console.
- SHA1 fingerprint is also confirmed to be correct.
- Unistalled app in my mobile, cleaned the project and re-deployed it.

But still I am getting this error.

This used to work fine before until I reinstalled windows in my PC and flashed a new ROM on the mobile, could it be because of these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restore the keystore from backup.  If you can't restore the keystore you'll have to generate new sha1 fingerprints and add them to the developer console.